# How to pass, with a custom button, the selected items to a controller?

Tags: development, module, plugin, custom-module

As seen in this question ([Add a custom button to a core backend component](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/5147/add-a-custom-button-to-a-core-backend-component)), I've created a simple plugin that adds a custom button on the com_content component.

When I click on this button, the site is redirected to the my_component controller, send task. But any of the selected items is sent to the my_component controller.

What should I do to pass the id of the selected articles to my controller?

Here is the source of my plugin:

```
class plgSystemSubscripcions extends JPlugin {
    public function onBeforeRender() {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();

        if ($app->isAdmin() === true) {
            $input = $app->input;

            if (($input->getCmd('option') === 'com_content' && $input->getCmd('view', 'articles') ===  'articles') ||
                ($input->getCmd('option') === 'com_docman'  && $input->getCmd('view', 'documents') === 'documents')) {
                $toolbar = JToolbar::getInstance('toolbar');

                $url = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_my_component&task=send&format=raw');
                $toolbar->appendButton('Link', 'mail', 'Mass email', $url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your button invokes only GET action. That means all input fields are not processed, but selected items are input fields. See the same problem in [this question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/7040/how-to-pass-with-a-custom-button-the-selected-items-to-a-controller).

Honestly I do not see any way how to pass them... If your button could submit a form that would do the trick, but as I understand it is not possible for custom buttons.

Comment: Wow, this is a big problem... Maybe I should create a complete backend module which shows all the articles and documents, with the "correct" button to send the emails...

Comment: I think that for this you will need a component not a module. Module is too small to show such a big portion of data.